# Generating a valid __RequestVerificationToken from C#

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

One of the most popular books on ASP.NET Core is "Pro ASP.NET Core 3" by Adam Freeman.

In chapters 7-11, he builds an example application, SportsStore.

[image]

As you can see, each product in the listing gets its own 'Add To Cart' button:

[image]

If we do 'view source' on this page, we'll see the following HTML for that item in the product list:

```html
<div class="card card-outline-primary m-1 p-1">

    <div class="bg-faded p-1">
        <h4>
            Kayak

            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" style="float:right">
                <small>$275.00</small>
            </span>
        </h4>
    </div>

    <form id="1" method="post" action="/Cart">

        <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="ID" name="ID" value="1" />

        <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="/" />

        <span class="card-text p-1">
            
            A boat for one person

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right" style="float:right">
                Add To Cart
            </button>

        </span>

    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8KKqNOS0gwdMvC0-bdjTwWlvCcBJldeidwIX5b2f24gYblS9X1sqCwJWIEsKKOSf8kut0SQsQRLF3R1XBSYZkPGnta9YzRK4tcQl8dq_0uWmjeUhm8yMe90fWDt_x0smmAD1lmb9-BxQF8y_7-IQSz4" /></form>

</div>
```

Note the `input` tag towards the bottom:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8KKqNOS0gwdMvC0-bdjTwWlvCcBJldeidwIX5b2f24gYblS9X1sqCwJWIEsKKOSf8kut0SQsQRLF3R1XBSYZkPGnta9YzRK4tcQl8dq_0uWmjeUhm8yMe90fWDt_x0smmAD1lmb9-BxQF8y_7-IQSz4" />
```

If we look at the [Views\Shared\ProductSummary.cshtml](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-3/blob/master/09%20-%20SportsStore%20-%20Cart/End%20of%20Chapter/SportsSln/SportsStore/Views/Shared/ProductSummary.cshtml) file in the SportsStore project, we'll see the code that is involved with generating these listing items:

```
@model Product

<div class="card card-outline-primary m-1 p-1">

    <div class="bg-faded p-1">
        <h4>
            @Model.Name

            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" style="float:right">
                <small>@Model.Price.ToString("c")</small>
            </span>
        </h4>
    </div>

    <form id="@Model.ID" asp-page="/Cart" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" asp-for="ID" />

        <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="@ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.PathAndQuery()" />

        <span class="card-text p-1">
            
            @Model.Description

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right" style="float:right">
                Add To Cart
            </button>

        </span>

    </form>

</div>
```

As you can see, the `form` element in this case doesn't have an explicit inclusion of the `input` tag with the `__RequestVerificationToken` value. This `form` thus appears to be a tag helper which takes care of generting the `input` tag with the `__RequestVerificationToken` token.

As an experiment, let's suppose I have added the following method to `Controllers\HomeController`:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ContentResult ButtonExample()
{
    var token = "...";

    return new ContentResult()
    {
        ContentType = "text/html",
        StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content =

            String.Format(

                @"<!DOCTYPE html>

                <html>
                    <body>
                        <form id=""1"" method=""post"" action=""/Cart"">

                            <input type=""hidden"" data-val=""true"" id=""ID"" name=""ID"" value=""1"" />
                        
                            <button type=""submit"">Add to Cart</button>
                        
                        </form>

                        <input name=""__RequestVerificationToken"" type=""hidden"" value=""{0}"" />
                    </body>
                </html>",

                token)

    };
}
```

As you can see, this generates a very simple page with a single button which is intended to add the product with ID value 1 (i.e. the Kayak) to the cart.

I of course need to pass an appropriate value for the `__RequestVerificationToken`.

My question is, is there a way to get this value from C# so that I can include it in the method above?

The idea as shown above would be to set the token value here:

```
var token = "...";
```

This is then interpolated into the string that generates the HTML using `String.Format`.

---

**UPDATE**

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages) mentions the following:

> To generate the anti-XSRF tokens, call the @Html.AntiForgeryToken method from an MVC view or @AntiForgery.GetHtml() from a Razor page.

So I guess the question is, how do we do the equivalent from C# directly instead of from an MVC view or Razor page?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the below code to your form which will generate the `__RequestVerificationToken`. It is used to prevent CSRF attacks [Prevent XSRF/CSRF attacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
</form>
```

Comment: Hey Rod. Note however that I'm generating the HTML directly from the method. Thus, the `@Html` won't work in this case.

Comment: Why do you want to generate the HTML? It would be easier if you let ASP.NET generate the input field with the token.

Comment: If you really want to create your own anti CSRF then check this site, https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/csrf-cross-site-request-forgery/ . Near the bottom of the page, there's an explanation on how to prevent the attack. What you need to do is generate a random string that is stored as session variable and also use that string as the token. Then on your action method, you can check if the session variable and the token is the same value.

Comment: Hey Rod. Well, yes, perhaps there is a way to roll my own anti-CSRF code. It just seems like somewhere in ASP.NET Core, there's a way to generate that `RequestVerificationToken` and I'm wondering if there's a way to get a hold of that token from within the C#.

Comment: Yes you can check my comment before this. The steps on how to mske your own.

Comment: Hey @Rod. If you're curious, see this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62745448/programmatically-generating-request-verification-token) for an approach that is quite straightforward.

I've marked this question as a duplicate of that one.