# Programmatically generating request verification token

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

Starting with an empty MVC project, here's my `Startup.cs`:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace AntiForgeryExample
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }
                
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseStatusCodePages();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my `HomeController.cs`:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Net;

namespace AntiForgeryExample
{
    public class XyzController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public string Fgh() => "fgh 1";

        [HttpGet]
        public ContentResult Efg()
        {
            return new ContentResult()
            {
                ContentType = "text/html",
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = @"<!DOCTYPE html>

                    <html>
                        <body>
                            <form method=""post"" action=""/Xyz/Fgh"">
                                <button type=""submit"">123</Button>
                            </form>                            
                        </body>
                    </html>"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The following line in `Startup.cs` adds the anti-forgery middleware:

```
services.AddMvc();
```

So, if we go to `http://localhost:52838/Xyz/Efg`, we get the simple page with a single button:

[image]

If we press the button, we get a 400 "Bad Request" response:

[image]

I'm assuming this is because we haven't passed a valid request verification token as part of the post. The `Fgh` method has the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute applied:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public string Fgh() => "fgh 1";
```

Thus a token is required when calling this method.

As described on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1), normally the code for this token will automatically be included if you use the `form` tag helper with ASP.NET Core MVC or a Razor Page. It will look something like this and be included as part of the `form` tag:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8NrAkS ... s2-m9Yw">
```

In the example program I show above, we're programmatically generating the HTML with the form.

My question is, is there a way to programmatically generate the required token from C#, without having to go through using an MVC view or Razor Page. The idea would be that we'd get the token value and then include the `input` tag:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="TOKEN VALUE HERE">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I shared this question on the `/r/dotnet` subreddit.

`/u/kenos1` provided a [very helpful answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/hm7dh4/aspnet_core_is_there_a_way_to_programmatically/fx3hpxn/) there:

> You can inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery and call GetTokens() on it.
>
> Here’s the documentation: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery.iantiforgery.gettokens?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Antiforgery_IAntiforgery_GetTokens_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpContext_)

As he mentions there, we inject `IAntiforgery` at the `XyzController` constructor:

```cs
private IAntiforgery antiforgery;

public XyzController(IAntiforgery antiforgery_)
{
    antiforgery = antiforgery_;
}
```

We call `GetAndStoreTokens` on the `IAntiforgery` instance that we injected:

```
var token_set = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext);
```

And finally, we use the resulting token in the generated HTML:

```cs
return new ContentResult()
{
    ContentType = "text/html",
    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
    Content = string.Format(@"<!DOCTYPE html>

        <html>
            <body>
                <form method=""post"" action=""/Xyz/Fgh"">
                    <button type=""submit"">123</Button>

                    <input name=""__RequestVerificationToken"" type=""hidden"" value=""{0}"">
                </form>                            
            </body>
        </html>",
        
        token_set.RequestToken)
};
```

Here is the controller file in its entirety:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using System.Net;

namespace AntiForgeryExample
{
    public class XyzController : Controller
    {
        private IAntiforgery antiforgery;

        public XyzController(IAntiforgery antiforgery_)
        {
            antiforgery = antiforgery_;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public string Fgh() => "fgh 1";

        [HttpGet]
        public ContentResult Efg()
        {
            var token_set = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext);
                                                
            return new ContentResult()
            {
                ContentType = "text/html",
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = string.Format(@"<!DOCTYPE html>

                    <html>
                        <body>
                            <form method=""post"" action=""/Xyz/Fgh"">
                                <button type=""submit"">123</Button>

                                <input name=""__RequestVerificationToken"" type=""hidden"" value=""{0}"">
                            </form>                            
                        </body>
                    </html>",
                    
                    token_set.RequestToken)
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The official ASP.NET Core 3.1 documentation mentions the `GetAndStoreTokens` method [here](http://The%20approach%20suggested%20by%20ksenos1%20above%20works%20well%20and%20is%20quite%20straightforward.%20%20The%20%5BGetAndStoreTokens%5D(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery.iantiforgery.getandstoretokens?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Antiforgery_IAntiforgery_GetAndStoreTokens_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpContext_)%20method%20does%20all%20the%20heavy%20lifting%20for%20you.%20%20See%20this%20answer%20for%20the%20full%20explanation%20of%20how%20the%20approach%20is%20implemented:%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/62777248/268581).

Comment: I spend 2 days on that to generate correct dynamic form on Razor Page, you save my life, thanks.

Comment: @Cheung Glad it helped! Consider voting up the question as well. :-)